# How to store Kafka direct stream JSON into Cassandra?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I have to save spark streaming data into Cassandra. Stream is coming from Kafka and Kafka message are in JSON format as shown below.

```
{
  "status": "NOT_AVAILABLE",
  "itemid": "550672332",
  "qty": 0,
  "lmts": "2017-11-18T10:39:21-08:00",
  "timestamp": 1511030361000
}
```

I have written below code to do that in Spark 2.2.0.

```scala
case class NliEvents(itemid: String, status: String, qty: String)

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
 .....
  val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
      ssc,
      PreferConsistent,
      Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
    )


    val valueStream = stream.map(_.value())
    val cassandraCrud = new CassandraOperations
    import com.datastax.spark.connector._

    val columns = SomeColumns("itemid", "status", "qty")
    val keySpace = configuration.getString(env + ".cassandra.keyspace")
    val gson = new Gson()
    import org.json4s._
    import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
    valueStream.foreachRDD((rdd, time) => {
      if (!rdd.isEmpty()) {
        val mapped = rdd.map(records => {
          val json = parse(records)
          val events = json.extract[NliEvents]
          events
        }
        )
        mapped.saveToCassandra(keySpace, "nli_events", columns)
      }
    })
}
```

When I am running this code I am getting

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.json4s.DefaultFormats$
```

error. May be I am not doing it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

can you replace your foreach statement with following code.

```
valueStream.mapPartitions(x => {
  val lst = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[NliEvents]()
  while (x.hasNext) {
    val json = parse(x.next())
    val events = json.extract[NliEvents]
    lst += events

  }
  lst.toList.iterator
  }
).saveToCassandra(keySpace, "nli_events",columns)
```

It should work. Let me know if you get any errors.